# Is there any evidence or example of "trade" or "money" in single cell organisms?

Tags: life

Single cells (like bacteria or eukaryotes) are extremely complex "machines" which can take input and produce output, and generally just *live* life. The question is, is there any example of "trade" (as in, "commerce") between cells, or within a cell at the molecular level (trading one protein for another, or a generalized "currency" where you could trade a general thing like money for anything else? I imagine there are, but not sure if people have put cells into this mental framework before.

Receptors on a cell seem to be somewhat a form of exchange/trade, "give me a molecule and I will start this chain reaction for you". There's probably many other forms of trade in this light. But what about money/currency?

This is, generally, an open-ended question. To make it closed. Provide one complete example of trade and money, and/or link to relevant research.

Comment: Another example might be Rhizobium in root nodules (see [here](http://labs.bio.unc.edu/Vision/pmabs/rhizobium.activity2.pdf)). It takes about 16 ATP to 'fix' one molecule of N2 into (2 NH3). The bacteria supply the plant with 'fixed' nitrogen, and the plant supplies the bacteria with nutrients and energy (possibly being the direct source  ATP?). 'Free' Rhizobium cannot 'fix' N2.

Comment: Look into [biofilms](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/36/5/990/660827) for bacterial mutualistic relationships.

Comment: Trade or currency implies a value placed on it - as in one cell could hold out for 2 ATP vs 1 for another, which requires thought ...so no. There is exchange, but it isn't trade or currency.

Comment: Cross-feeding is a common type of symbiotic interaction in which one organism can utilize a substance produced but not utilized by another organism. It's very common in bacterial communities, and often mutualistic (though not always). But there's no perfect analog for currency in this context. More like bartering goods and services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lichens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) might be such an example. Algae living with fungi in a mutualistic relationship.

Comment: These are multicellular organisms, right? I am looking for single celled organisms or within single celled organisms.

Comment: @Lance Plenty of unicellular fungi combine with unicellular photosynthetic green algae or cyanobacteria to form lichens. Check out the article in my link.